# How to use ndk-build?

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

so I downloaded this application https://github.com/Teaonly/android-eye, which is an IP camera simple application that uses some libraries, unfortunately my short knowledge of android does not include working with libraries. My question is how, eventually, could I build those libraries up?  There's a jni folder with Android.mk inside with the rest of the code of those libraries.

How do I compile them? I tried

```
ndk-build C:\Downloads\EyeMaster\jni\
```

but it says "Wrong directory".

Comment: can you post all the error message here?

Comment: did you set the PATH of your android-ndk? else you have to write the full path for ndk-build command